Creating summary() of a lavaan.mi object (runMI())
So I am trying to use the runMI() function of the semTools package to fit a multiple impute ordinal MG-CFA model. However, it seems like R isn't finding the correct summary() methods for lavaan.mi-class objects, instead using the method for lavaanList-class objects, as per this discussion. However, equally to the original post of that discussion, I only get ave.est values. Anyone knows how to fix the problem, so that the summary function on a runMI-generated lavaan.mi-class object works correctly? An example of how it should actually work can be found in the third post of this dicussion, where OP had a similar problem.
Here you can see my steps on a simulated dataframe that I created based on the runMI documentation:
rm(list=ls()) # Clean workspace
options(scipen=10000) # Set scientific notation
library(tidyverse)
library(lavaan) # For CFA
library(semTools) # For runMI
set.seed(121012) # For reproducibility

# Create simulated categorical dataset with missing values
popModel <- "
f1 =~ 0.6*y1 + 0.6*y2 + 0.6*y3 + 0.6*y4
y1 ~*~ 1*y1
y2 ~*~ 1*y2
y3 ~*~ 1*y3
y4 ~*~ 1*y4
f1 ~~ 1*f1
y1 | 0.5*t1
y2 | 0.25*t1
y3 | 0*t1
y4 | -0.5*t1
"

dat <- simulateData(popModel, sample.nobs  = 200L)
miss.pat <- matrix(as.logical(rbinom(prod(dim(dat)), 1, 0.2)), nrow(dat), ncol(dat))
dat[miss.pat] <- NA

# Convert columns to factors with specified levels
dat$y1 <- factor(dat$y1, levels = c(1, 2))
dat$y2 <- factor(dat$y2, levels = c(1, 2))
dat$y3 <- factor(dat$y3, levels = c(1, 2))
dat$y4 <- factor(dat$y4, levels = c(1, 2))

# Define categories for a grouping variable school
schools <- c("Marx", "Durkheim", "Weber", "Comte")

# Sample the school categories randomly for each row
dat$school <- sample(schools, size = nrow(dat), replace = TRUE)

# Define Ordinal MG-CFA model
analyzeModel <- "
f1 =~ y1 + y2 + y3 + y4
y1 ~*~ 1*y1
y2 ~*~ 1*y2
y3 ~*~ 1*y3
y4 ~*~ 1*y4
"
# Create predictor matrix
predictormatrix<-quickpred(dat)

# Impute 5 datasets (common practice)
dat_imp <- mice(data = dat, 
                           predictorMatrix = predictormatrix,
                           m = 5, 
                           # Specify imputation method for ordinal data
                           method = "polr")

mice.imp <- NULL
for(i in 1:5) mice.imp[[i]] <- complete(dat_imp, action=i, inc=FALSE)  

# run lavaan with previously imputed data using runMI
out2 <- semTools::runMI(analyzeModel, 
                        data = mice.imp,
                        fun = "cfa",
                        meanstructure = TRUE,
                        group = "school", ordered = TRUE, 
                        std.lv = TRUE)

detach("package:tidyverse", unload = TRUE)
library(semTools)

summary(out2)

I tried explicitly loading semTools as suggested in the linked discussions, however that does not seem to work. I updated all the relevant packages and R and RStudio to their latest non-dev versions, but that also had no effect.
Here you can see my sessionInfo() output in case it comes handy.
> sessionInfo()
R version 4.3.3 (2024-02-29 ucrt)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows 11 x64 (build 22631)

Matrix products: default


locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=English_United Kingdom.utf8  LC_CTYPE=English_United Kingdom.utf8   
[3] LC_MONETARY=English_United Kingdom.utf8 LC_NUMERIC=C                           
[5] LC_TIME=English_United Kingdom.utf8    

time zone: Europe/Berlin
tzcode source: internal

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
 [1] mice_3.16.0      stargazer_5.2.3  lavaanPlot_0.8.1 tidySEM_0.2.6    OpenMx_2.21.11  
 [6] reshape2_1.4.4   sirt_4.1-15      blavaan_0.5-4    Rcpp_1.0.11      psych_2.4.3     
[11] semTools_0.5-6   lavaan_0.6-17    factoextra_1.0.7 lubridate_1.9.3  forcats_1.0.0   
[16] stringr_1.5.1    dplyr_1.1.3      purrr_1.0.2      readr_2.1.5      tidyr_1.3.1     
[21] tibble_3.2.1     ggplot2_3.5.1   

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
  [1] RColorBrewer_1.1-3    shape_1.4.6.1         rstudioapi_0.16.0    
  [4] jsonlite_1.8.8        magrittr_2.0.3        jomo_2.7-6           
  [7] estimability_1.5      nloptr_2.0.3          farver_2.1.1         
 [10] rmarkdown_2.26        ragg_1.3.0            vctrs_0.6.3          
 [13] minqa_1.2.6           CompQuadForm_1.4.3    htmltools_0.5.7      
 [16] broom_1.0.5           mitml_0.4-5           parallelly_1.37.1    
 [19] StanHeaders_2.32.6    htmlwidgets_1.6.4     gsubfn_0.7           
 [22] plyr_1.8.9            sandwich_3.1-0        emmeans_1.10.1       
 [25] zoo_1.8-12            admisc_0.35           igraph_2.0.3         
 [28] iterators_1.0.14      lifecycle_1.0.4       pkgconfig_2.0.3      
 [31] Matrix_1.6-1          R6_2.5.1              fastmap_1.1.1        
 [34] future_1.33.2         digest_0.6.33         colorspace_2.1-0     
 [37] bain_0.2.10           textshaping_0.3.7     labeling_0.4.3       
 [40] progressr_0.14.0      fansi_1.0.4           timechange_0.3.0     
 [43] httr_1.4.7            abind_1.4-5           compiler_4.3.3       
 [46] withr_3.0.0           pander_0.6.5          backports_1.4.1      
 [49] inline_0.3.19         carData_3.0-5         fastDummies_1.7.3    
 [52] QuickJSR_1.1.3        pkgbuild_1.4.4        pan_1.9              
 [55] MASS_7.3-60.0.1       loo_2.7.0             tools_4.3.3          
 [58] pbivnorm_0.6.0        MplusAutomation_1.1.1 future.apply_1.11.2  
 [61] nnet_7.3-19           glue_1.6.2            quadprog_1.5-8       
 [64] dbscan_1.1-12         DiagrammeR_1.0.11     nlme_3.1-164         
 [67] grid_4.3.3            checkmate_2.3.1       generics_0.1.3       
 [70] gtable_0.3.5          tzdb_0.4.0            data.table_1.14.8    
 [73] hms_1.1.3             car_3.1-2             utf8_1.2.3           
 [76] ggrepel_0.9.5         RANN_2.6.1            foreach_1.5.2        
 [79] pillar_1.9.0          splines_4.3.3         lattice_0.22-5       
 [82] survival_3.5-8        tidyselect_1.2.1      pbapply_1.7-2        
 [85] knitr_1.46            gridExtra_2.3         CDM_8.2-6            
 [88] stats4_4.3.3          xfun_0.43             texreg_1.39.3        
 [91] matrixStats_1.3.0     rstan_2.32.6          proto_1.0.0          
 [94] visNetwork_2.1.2      stringi_1.8.3         yaml_2.3.8           
 [97] boot_1.3-29           evaluate_0.23         codetools_0.2-19     
[100] nonnest2_0.5-6        cli_3.6.1             TAM_4.2-21           
[103] rpart_4.1.23          RcppParallel_5.1.7    xtable_1.8-4         
[106] systemfonts_1.0.6     munsell_0.5.1         globals_0.16.3       
[109] polycor_0.8-1         coda_0.19-4.1         parallel_4.3.3       
[112] rstantools_2.4.0      ellipsis_0.3.2        bayesplot_1.11.1     
[115] lme4_1.1-35.3         listenv_0.9.1         glmnet_4.1-8         
[118] mvtnorm_1.2-3         scales_1.3.0          crayon_1.5.2         
[121] tmvnsim_1.0-2         rlang_1.1.1           mnormt_2.1.1  

Any help is extremely appreciated, as I am under some time pressure to submit my thesis and this is the last analysis part I have to conduct. Thanks!

There is no reason to load library(tidyverse) in your reprex, since it is not used; but library(mice) is necessary.  I run your example without tidyverse (but with mice), and it works fine using R 4.3.3, although I have the latest development versions of lavaan and semTools installed from GitHub.  Try remotes::install_github("yrosseel/lavaan") and remotes::install_github("simsem/semTools/semTools"), then restarting R before trying again (without tidyverse, which might load packages that interfere with the path to semTools methods).
